# Is it possible to show a call trace in ansible when failure occurs?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to traceback the caller file in ansible?

Below is my example

```
---
# ./roles/my_role/tasks/main.yml

- include_tasks: install.yml

- include_tasks: configure.yml
```

I may include some more files like `check_docker.yml` and `install_docker.yml` inside install.yml

If failure occurs in `install_docker.yml` , If call trace like  `install.yml <line number>-> install_docker.yml <line num>` then it will be easier to figure out the root cause.

Is it possible in Ansible?

Comment: Are you running in verbose mode `-v`? In my experience that's all required for ansible to show the exact place where something fails. Also, since each task does one thing only, you automatically have it nailed down to a few lines. The main problem (for me) is when the YAML file is not correct, and ansible gives back some parsing errors that often don't lead to the actual line that is wrong, but that's the nature of YAML.

Answer (score 0):

See [Debugging tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#debugging-tasks) and enable [debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#enabling-the-debugger-with-the-debugger-keyword). For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  debugger: on_failed
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: install_docker.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat install_docker.yml
- name: Docker failed
  command: /usr/bin/false
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_tasks] ****
included: /export/scratch/tmp/install_docker.yml for localhost

TASK [Docker failed] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - /usr/bin/false
  delta: '0:00:00.003223'
  end: '2020-10-29 10:55:22.457982'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-10-29 10:55:22.454759'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
[localhost] TASK: Docker failed (debug)> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF  c  continue  h  help  p  pprint  q  quit  r  redo  u  update_task

[localhost] TASK: Docker failed (debug)>
```

---

Increase verbosity to get more details. For example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test-26.yml -vvv

  ...

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - /usr/bin/false
  delta: '0:00:00.002791'
  end: '2020-10-29 10:57:33.372253'
  invocation:
    module_args:
      _raw_params: /usr/bin/false
      _uses_shell: false
      argv: null
      chdir: null
      creates: null
      executable: null
      removes: null
      stdin: null
      stdin_add_newline: true
      strip_empty_ends: true
      warn: true
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-10-29 10:57:33.369462'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
[localhost] TASK: Docker failed (debug)>
```